# Middleware for Eloquent queries before results returned

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

There are certain fields in a table whose values need to be calculated on each query, or at least the first time they are found to be null.

For instance, suppose there is the simple field `profit` that must go through a calculation in PHP by calling the model's method `profit()` before the actual field `profit` field value can be set.

Is there middleware in Eloquent that would allow me to alter the value of that field with each row returned?

Comment: It sort of sounds like Mutators are what you're looking for? http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators

Answer (score 0):

Also good to not use Middleware for such data requests, as the model should own (be responsible) for the data.

Middleware is good for intercepting the request from a technical perspective i.e. Is the user logged in, is the user IP blocked?